# Multiplying a constant to each element of an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need to multiply each element of an array to a constant.

I get

> run time 13 type mismatch

at the line `va(i, j) = va(i, j) * 10000`.

I checked online and the syntax should be ok.

```vb
Sub arr()
    
    Dim va As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    va = Range("A1:f37").Value
    For i = LBound(va, 1) To UBound(va, 1)
        For j = LBound(va, 2) To UBound(va, 2)
            va(i, j) = va(i, j) * 10000
        Next
    Next
    Range("A1:f37").Value = va
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do some debugging, but probably you have a non-numeric cell. You can do this with pastespecial.

Comment: When it fails go into Debug mode and enter `? va(i, j)` in the immediate pane and hit enter: what does it output?

Comment: Thank you very much! you were right, it was one non numeric value.

Comment: Aside: Also make sure you always qualify your ranges with the relevant sheets.